# Prove if sequence is convergent then $a = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $a > 0$ and $b^2 < 4ac$. Consider the sequence:

$x_n = \sqrt{an^2 + bn +c} -n$ , $n\ge1$

I'm supposed to prove that if $x_n$ is convergent then $a = 1$. My hint is that the conjugate will help but I'm not really sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. We prefer if you write your questions using MathJax. To learn how to use MathJax (it's really not too hard), see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference You can look at what I've done by clicking "edit". Feel free to have a play around with it. :-)

Comment: As for the question itself, I'd give a further hint in the same vein: the right hand side can be written as $$\frac{(\sqrt{an^2 + bn + c} - n)(\sqrt{an^2 + bn + c} + n)}{\sqrt{an^2 + bn + c} + n}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **conjugate** write
$$\lim_\infty\sqrt{an^2+bn+c}-n=\lim_\infty\dfrac{(a-1)n^2+bn+c}{\sqrt{an^2+bn+c}+n}=\lim_\infty\dfrac{(a-1)n^2+bn+c}{n\left(\sqrt{a+\frac{b}{n}+\frac{c}{n^2}}+1\right)}$$
exists if $a-1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I would just pull a factor $n\sqrt a$ out of the square root, then show the remaining square root goes to $1$.  The expression then goes as $n(\sqrt a-1)$ which diverges unless $a=1$